# No puedo Convertir int a string

Tags: java, netbeans

Soy nuevo en este mundo y estoy realizando un proyecto para el estudio, en el código que estoy realizando una de las líneas me sale con error.

```
package Controlador;

import Controlador.exceptions.PreexistingEntityException;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 *
 * @author Danielk8
 */
public class MaterialControl implements ActionListener {
       Vista.GestionDatos_CrearMaterial materialVista;
       Modelo.Materiales materialModelo;
       Controlador.MaterialesJpaController gestorMaterialModelo;
       
       public MaterialControl(Vista.GestionDatos_CrearMaterial materialVista){
           
           this.materialVista=materialVista;
           EntityManagerFactory emf= Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("TallerMotosRoadFirePU");
           gestorMaterialModelo= new Controlador.MaterialesJpaController(emf); 
       }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource().equals(materialVista.btn_crear)){
            
            try{
            String Identificacion=materialVista.txt_identificacion.getText();
            String Descripcion=materialVista.txt_descripcion.getText();
            String CodigoBarras=materialVista.txt_cbarras.getText();
            String Embalaje=materialVista.txt_embalaje.getText();
            String FamiliaArticulos=materialVista.cbo_farticulos.getSelectedItem().toString();
            String IndicadorImpuestos=materialVista.txt_impuestos.getText();
            String PrecioCompra=materialVista.txt_pcompra.getText();
            String IdProveedor=materialVista.txt_idproveedor.getText();
            String PrecioVenta=materialVista.txt_pventa.getText();
            String Estado=materialVista.cbo_estado.getSelectedItem().toString();
            SimpleDateFormat formato = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yy");
            String Fechacreacion = formato.format(materialVista.Dtd_fcreacion.getDate());
        
            materialModelo= new Modelo.Materiales();
            materialModelo.setIdMaterial(new Integer(Identificacion));
            materialModelo.setDescMaterial(Descripcion);
            materialModelo.setCodbarrasMaterial(CodigoBarras);
            materialModelo.setEmbalajeMaterial(new Integer(Embalaje));
            materialModelo.setFliaarticulosMaterial(FamiliaArticulos);
            materialModelo.setIndicadorimpuestoMaterial(new Integer(IndicadorImpuestos));
            materialModelo.setPreciocompraMaterial(new Integer(PrecioCompra));
            materialModelo.setIdProvMaterial(new Integer(IdProveedor));
            materialModelo.setPrecioventaMaterial(new Integer(PrecioVenta));
            materialModelo.setEstadoMaterial(Estado);
            materialModelo.setFcreacionMaterial(new Date(Fechacreacion));
            
            
            gestorMaterialModelo.create(materialModelo);
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(materialVista, "Material Creado Exitosamente");
            }catch (Exception ex) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(materialVista, "Material ya Existe");
                Logger.getLogger(ProveedorControl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }     
        
        if(e.getSource().equals(materialVista.btn_nuevo)){
            materialVista.txt_identificacion.setText(null);
            materialVista.txt_descripcion.setText(null);
            materialVista.txt_cbarras.setText(null);
            materialVista.txt_embalaje.setText(null);
            materialVista.cbo_farticulos.setSelectedItem("No Registra");
            materialVista.txt_impuestos.setText(null);
            materialVista.txt_pcompra.setText(null);
            materialVista.txt_idproveedor.setText(null);
            materialVista.txt_pventa.setText(null);
            materialVista.cbo_estado.setSelectedItem("Activo");
            materialVista.Dtd_fcreacion.setDate(null);
        }
    } 
}
```

la linea que presenta el error es el siguiente:
materialModelo.setIdProvMaterial(new Integer(IdProveedor));

el problema es incompatible types: Integer cannot be converted to Proveedor, no se si hay algún problema ya que esto esta conectado a una base de datos y en esta tabla es una llave foránea y en la de proveedor es una llave principal.

Gracias de antemano por la ayuda que me puedan prestar.

Comment: No sé si has escritor mal el mensaje de error, pero si es como está escrito la parecer IdProvMaterial es de tipo Proveedor y no un Integer.

Comment: El problema no se si sea ese, es que tengo una clase llamada proveedor con el dato idProv y es la llave principal de esa tabla y donde presenta el error, el campo es una llave foranea

Comment: `materialModelo.setIdProvMaterial(new Integer(IdProveedor))` por el mensaje de error se puede pensar que `setIdProvMaterial ` recibe como parámetro un data de tipo `Proveedor`, por tal razón te dice que no puede convertir un `Integer`  a `Proveedor`. Es como si el metodo fuera `setIdProvMaterial(Proveedor value)` en lugar de ser `setIdProvMaterial(Integer valu)`. Verifica cuál de los dos es. `value` es un nombre arbitrario puede ser otro.